# New FFMPEG; "[swscaler @ 0xa314080] Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speedloss"

Tags: ubuntu, video, ffmpeg

related to ; [Create a screencast with ffmpeg: how to keep video+audio in sync?](https://superuser.com/questions/725581/create-a-screencast-with-ffmpeg-how-to-keep-videoaudio-in-sync/728739?noredirect=1#comment934589_728739)

```
ffmpeg version 2.2.git Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
```

built on Mar 13 2014 16:08:45 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9)

produces an error

```
"[swscaler @ 0xa314080] Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speedloss"
```

The end result is a serious a/v sync issue, with the video as if it's in Fast-forward.

Has anyone encountered this problem? Any ideas for solutions?

The goal is screencasting;

```
    ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:2,0 -f x11grab -r 30 -s 1920x1072 -i :0.0 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k -sameq /media/username/library-portable/video-studio/transfer-bin/BTSvlog02.avi
ffmpeg version 2.2.git Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Mar 13 2014 16:08:45 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/username/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/home/username/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/username/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/username/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      52. 66.101 / 52. 66.101
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavdevice    55. 11.100 / 55. 11.100
  libavfilter     4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Option 'sameq' was removed. If you are looking for an option to preserve the quality (which is not what -sameq was for), use -qscale 0 or an equivalent quality factor option.
Failed to set value '1' for option 'sameq': Invalid argument
Error parsing global options: Invalid argument
```

used to work.

I tried (and just tried again); (*added/updated Monday, March 17th, 2014*)

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:2,0 -f x11grab -r 30 -s 1920x1080 -i :0.0 -acodec libmp3lame -ab 320k /media/username/library-portable/video-studio/transfer-bin/BTSvlog03.avi
ffmpeg version 2.2.git Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Mar 13 2014 16:08:45 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/username/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/home/username/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/username/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/home/username/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-nonfree --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      52. 66.101 / 52. 66.101
  libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
  libavformat    55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
  libavdevice    55. 11.100 / 55. 11.100
  libavfilter     4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, alsa, from 'hw:2,0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1395098882.312775, bitrate: 1536 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
[x11grab @ 0x9ea2c20] device: :0.0 -> display: :0.0 x: 0 y: 0 width: 1920 height: 1080
[x11grab @ 0x9ea2c20] shared memory extension found
Input #1, x11grab, from ':0.0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1395098882.360550, bitrate: 1990656 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[0] / 0x524742), bgr0, 1920x1080, 1990656 kb/s, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 30 tbc
Output #0, avi, to '/media/username/library-portable/video-studio/transfer-bin/BTSvlog03.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf55.34.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (FMP4 / 0x34504D46), yuv420p, 1920x1080, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 30 tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) (U[0][0][0] / 0x0055), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 320 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo -> mpeg4)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le -> libmp3lame)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x9e81080] Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speedloss
[alsa @ 0x9e98d00] ALSA buffer xrun.743kB time=00:00:00.13 bitrate=45644.2kbits/s    
[alsa @ 0x9e98d00] ALSA buffer xrun.1067kB time=00:00:01.70 bitrate=5131.9kbits/s    
[alsa @ 0x9e98d00] ALSA buffer xrun.2175kB time=00:00:05.95 bitrate=2994.1kbits/s    
[alsa @ 0x9e98d00] ALSA buffer xrun.5550kB time=00:00:17.68 bitrate=2570.6kbits/s    
frame=  580 fps=9.9 q=31.0 Lsize=    6540kB time=00:00:50.28 bitrate=1065.5kbits/s    
video:6433kB audio:34kB subtitle:0 data:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 1.125390%
Received signal 2: terminating.
```

Same results;

*Note, the FFMPEG issue mostly likely is a Ubuntu issue. I'm on Kubuntu 13.10 . There has been a split in the FFMPEG community and the Ubuntu group ended up on the side that left the FFMPEG project.

Comment: drop the option `-sameq` first and try again. ffmpeg version seems like the real thing although i can't say if any libraries are conflicting. But try dropping `-sameq` first.

Comment: Comments won't allow the code, so I updated the question. Basically, same results.

Comment: I am getting this warning while merging multiple video files :(

Comment: I'm just getting into FFmpeg development. I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: As elaborated in my comment below, the message is practically meaningless but a note to the future reader: The command used here is defaulting to the libx264 software encoder. This is enormously CPU-intensive. You might want to use your hardware acceleration capabilities (VAAPI / QSV) to offload most of the work and use libx264 afterwards as a second pass and only if you really really want the best possible compression / quality available. Oh and MP3 is 2014. Meanwhile there is OPUS (libopus).

Answer (score 7):

1080 / 16 = 67.5, which is not a whole number, presumably leading to writing 68 items to a buffer with 67 slots, potentially crashing the encoder. Something else might round up to 68, gradually deviating the reported number of processed bits.

According to [this thread](http://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?t=167010), the offending code is:

```
420 if ( (uintptr_t)dst[0]%16 || (uintptr_t)dst[1]%16 || (uintptr_t)dst[2]%16
421 || (uintptr_t)src[0]%16 || (uintptr_t)src[1]%16 || (uintptr_t)src[2]%16
422 || dstStride[0]%16 || dstStride[1]%16 || dstStride[2]%16 || dstStride[3]%16
423 || srcStride[0]%16 || srcStride[1]%16 || srcStride[2]%16 || srcStride[3]%16
424 ) {
425 static int warnedAlready=0;
426 int cpu_flags = av_get_cpu_flags();
427 if (HAVE_MMXEXT && (cpu_flags & AV_CPU_FLAG_SSE2) && !warnedAlready){
428 av_log(c, AV_LOG_WARNING, "Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speedloss\n");
429 warnedAlready=1;
430 }
431 }
```

1080 % 16 = 8, and the code expects 0, so the size should be a multiple of 16.

As noted in the comment, that's just a performance warning. I'd still try:

1. A different resolution to rule that out.
2. Different codecs and/or containers. Opus > AAC > Vorbis > MP3. And Matroska > AVI.
3. Different distro. In my experience Ubuntu breaks something every update, so try rolling stable openSuSE Tumbleweed, rolling unstable Manjaro, polished and stable Mint, Bodhi, or Linuxfx.

Comment: This is not more than a nice hint. This code reads: If the CPU supports [Extended MMX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_MMX) and furthermore [SSE2 instructions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE2) and the input dimensions are not a multiple of 16, print a warning that we're not running on warp-speed. That is, we're loosing a few percent in speed since the dimensions are not a perfect multiple of the vector instruction lengths. Cool message somehow!

Comment: **P.s.** I was now curious on this one and yes, the message disappears as expected if you set the input dimensions to a multiple of 16 but I was unable to measure a real difference ( (0 +- 1) % ).